# MySQL FIND_IN_SET() not working with JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
... | products | ...
... | 1, 5, 5  | ...
... | 3, 1, 6  | ...
```

And this query:

```
SELECT
  orders.id, 
  orders.user_id, 
  users.username, 
  orders.products, 
  orders.rating, 
  orders.payment, 
  orders.comment 
FROM 
  orders JOIN users 
  ON orders.user_id = users.id 
WHERE 
  FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE(orders.products, ' ', '')) > 0;
```

I need to get these rows but it gives me no result, I've tried the query using only the table `orders`, and it works. So why it does not work with `JOIN`?

Comment: It's still a good idea to abandon storing comma separated lists in columns as [zerkms](http://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) told you. But what's your problem? Maybe you haven't got  a suitable user in your table users. Your query works, see [demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39344e/1).

Comment: @VMai You're right, I didn't have the right user. As of My choice to use CSV, Ihave this orders table, creating a separate table For all these records won't be easy...

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
  orders.id, 
  orders.user_id, 
  users.username, 
  orders.products, 
  orders.rating, 
  orders.payment, 
  orders.comment 
FROM 
  orders JOIN users 
  ON orders.id = users.id 
WHERE 
  FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE(orders.products, ' ', '')) > 0;
```

I have changed `user_id` to `id` in the line that joins the two tables.